# Do I need to modify the app if I connected CloudFront with S3?

Tags: amazon-s3, mobile-application

So, I have an app with people who can post videos, make a profile etc.

I don't have so much experience with AWS, but I'm confused. I followed a tutorial about "How to connect S3 with CloudFront" and I don't know if I need to do more.

So, on Origin domain I selected my S3 Bucket and on "Allowed HTTP" only GET, HEAD. And the other settings like all edge locations.

My question is, my app still have performance issues, Do I need to modify anything else? Like, when I go to my app and tap on the share button, the share link is s3bucket...... , I didn't change it to my website yet.

Comment: You want to serve your content through cloudfront with your website url. Is that correct?

Comment: By website you mean my domain and not that address(s3bucket...), no. I want to know if I need to modify something else on my app for CloudFront to work. If I connected the CloudFront with S3, it means that I have CDN, right? And my videos from the app should work with the CDN

Comment: yes you can access any content in your bucket using the Cdn url if the bucket allows public read.

Comment: Yes, the bucket is public. Thank you! I thought I need to modify something in my app for CloudFront to work properly!